# What is PYTHONPATH counterpart for Lua?

Tags: lua, torch

I like to make some of my own classes available system-wide in Torch7. In python it is enough to give the class files paths to PYTHONPATH environment variable. Is there any equal way to do this for Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environmental variable you are looking for is [`LUA_PATH`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path)

> At start-up, Lua initializes this [`package.path`] variable with the value of the environment variable `LUA_PATH_5_3` or the environment variable `LUA_PATH` or with a default path defined in `luaconf.h`, if those environment variables are not defined. Any ";;" in the value of the environment variable is replaced by the default path.

For example, to have Lua look for files in `/home/bob/lualibs`, you would set `LUA_PATH` to `/home/bob/lualibs;;`